# firebase logout not working on FB hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      console.log("ADMIN is IN");
     // window.location.href = "admin.html"
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      console.log("No ADMIN");
      window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
  });


function logout(){
    console.log("Function RAN");
    firebase.auth().signOut()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("FINE LOGOUT WORKED");
    window.location.href = "login.html";
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

Question 1:- here is my code it work fine on localhost but when i deploy it to firebase hosting it doesn't work?

Question 2:- Can i generate static html files from Cloud function to serve on firebase hosting.

Comment: For question 1: what happens deployed? Can you sign in properly and so on. If you could give a clear step by step of what happens on localhost vs deployed, that would help. Also, might be worth noting what sign in mechanisms you are using - thanks!

Comment: Yes, Sign In works properly on localhost and on firebase hosting. Only facing problem with logout. when deployed if I go to application tab inside inspect and delete local Storage / Session Storage and cookies then it logout. I am using Email/Password sign in Method. Thanks

Comment: Does the error log output anything? From your code it looks like there should be some log output in either case

Comment: there is no error as it run .then funtion "console.log("FINE LOGOUT WORKED");" I have to manually delete Applciation localStorgae then i get logout.
you can check at 
https://notification-te.firebaseapp.com/admin.html
admin@admin.com
password

now its working fine

Comment: Hey Sh Malik, I noticed you double include libraries in your code `firebase.js` and `firebase-app.js` and `firebase-auth.js`. Can you remove one version and keep the other. I can see the issue in your app but I am having a problem replicating it on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 2: Yes! Take a look at the docs page on [serving dynamic content with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

Comment: Thanks ... That was point in right direction... But I was expecting more from FB functions ... I want to generate static .html files viva functions as i will update my portfolio once in a month.

Comment: Hosting can cache the output, so you wont be generating it every time, and you can tune the length of that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I can confirm the issue is because you are double including the same Firebase source code. When I removed one version, the code works. Either use the hosting provided source code or the gstatic versions. You can't use both.